# Не добавлять не уникальный обьект в массив

Tags: javascript

Есть массив обьектов fruits, из которого, обьекты могут добавляются в массив selected.

```
let fruits = [{Id: 1, Name: 'Apple'}, {Id: 2, Name: 'Pear'},
{ Id: 3, Name: 'Orange'}, { Id: 4, Name: 'Plum'}, { Id: 5, Name: 'Cherry'}];

let selected = [{Id: 3, Name: 'Orange'}];
```

Как сделать, чтобы обьекты из fruits не добавлялись в selected, если там уже есть
похожий обьект. Например, чтобы в selected больше не добавлялся обьект с Id = 3, а добавились все остальные? Важна поддержка IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let fruits = [
  { Id: 1, Name: 'Apple' }, 
  { Id: 2, Name: 'Pear' },
  { Id: 3, Name: 'Orange' }, 
  { Id: 4, Name: 'Plum' }, 
  { Id: 5, Name: 'Cherry' }
];
let selected = [{Id: 3, Name: 'Orange'}];

function addUniqueIds(src, dst) {
  var lookup = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < dst.length; i++) {
    lookup[dst[i].Id] = true;
  }  
  for (var i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
    if (!lookup[src[i].Id]) {
      lookup[src[i].Id] = true;
      dst.push(src[i]);
    }
  }
}

addUniqueIds(fruits, selected);
console.log(selected.length, selected);
```

Answer (score 1):

А если вдруг кому не так важна поддержка ie, то вот:

**1. Если порядок полей не меняется**

```js
const fruits = [{Id: 1, Name: 'Apple'}, {Id: 2, Name: 'Pear'}, { Id: 3, Name: 'Orange'}, { Id: 4, Name: 'Plum'}, { Id: 5, Name: 'Cherry'}];

const selected = [{Id: 3, Name: 'Orange'}];

const newSelect = selected.map((item) => JSON.stringify(item));

const result = fruits.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if(!newSelect.includes(JSON.stringify(item))) {
    return acc.concat(item);
  }
  return acc;
}, selected)

console.log(result)
```

**2. Если порядок полей меняется** (замечание от @n3r0bi0m4n)

```js
const fruits = [{Id: 1, Name: 'Apple'}, {Id: 2, Name: 'Pear'}, { Id: 3, Name: 'Orange'}, { Id: 4, Name: 'Plum'}, { Id: 5, Name: 'Cherry'}];

const selected = [{Name: 'Orange', Id: 3}, {Name: 'Pear', Id: 2}];

const newSelect = selected.map((item) => (item.Id));

const result = fruits.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if(!newSelect.includes(item.Id)) {
    return acc.concat(item);
  }
  return acc;
}, selected)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: а если (внезапно) порядок полей где-нибудь поменяется? `{Name: 'Orange', Id: 3}` :)

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n, с чего бы? Из условия задачи такой сценарий не следует. Но если поменяется, значит, нужно будет слегка подкорректировать решение.

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n, я дополнил ответ, добавив второй вариант. Спасибо за замечание!